# Is 'Where do you buy yogurt from?' grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-choice

Are all of these sentences sound natural?

> Where do you buy yoghurt?
>   Where do you buy yoghurt from?
>
> I buy it from Kurosh Supermarket.
>   I buy it at Kurosh Supermarket.
>   I buy it in Kurosh Supermarket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your questions, there's a minor emphatic difference. If I were eating yogurt at your house, and I thought it was really delicious, I might ask:

> Where do you buy yogurt from?

It places extra emphasis on the fact that I really want to know where to buy this yogurt, probably so I can go there to buy it for myself. However, I could place the same kind of emphasis using "this" and past tense:

> Where did you buy this yogurt?

It would also be basically the same to use "at":

> Where do you buy yogurt at?

When it comes to the answers, the simple answer is that I would be *most likely* to simply match the preposition you used in your question. So, if you asked:

> Where do you buy yogurt from?

My most likely reply would be:

> From Kurosh supermarket.

If you ask, simply:

> Where do you buy yogurt?

My most likely reply would be:

> At Kurosh supermarket.

The more likely scenario for using "in" might be something like the following:

> While I was shopping for pistachios in Kurosh supermarket, I also bought yogurt.

Note that using "from" with "Kurosh supermarket" gives it a slight element of personification. It would be completely incorrect so say "I buy yogurt at Kathy Smith." If you buy something from *a person*, you must use "from." If you buy it at *a place*, then you would usually say *at*, but *from* feels a bit more affectionate and personal.

Answer (score 0):

They are all grammatically correct.

The second might be discouraged in some style guides as it ends in a preposition. However such sentences are normal, and correct in standard English. There is an alternate form "From where do you buy yogurt?" But his is only found in very formal styles of English.

However, "Where do you buy yogurt?" is complete and correct. This would be the question I would use. The response could use "from", "at" or "in", though in most contexts "at" seems best, as you are treating the supermarket as single location.